# Distributions representable as Ito diffusions

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

This is inspired by the [following question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/416483/5887). Let $X_t$ be an Ito diffusion on the interval $t\in [0,1]$:
$$
  \mathrm dX_t = a(X_t)\mathrm dt+ b(X_t)\mathrm dW_t
$$
where say $a,b$ are Lipschitz continuous functions. Let us denote by $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ the class of all Borel measures on $\Bbb R$.

1. Let $\alpha\in \mathcal P(\Bbb R)$. Is it possible to characterize the class $\mathcal P_\alpha$ of all possible distributions of $X_1$ given the fact that $X_0\sim \alpha$?
2. Given $\beta\in \mathcal P_\alpha$, is it possible to choose $a$ and $b$ in some constructive way?